# javassist with Glassfish - javassist.NotFoundException - Failed instrumenting class from springframework

Tags: java, bytecode, agent, javassist, javaagents

When using javassist to instrument a `com.sun.net.*` class I could successfully use .insertAfter method.
However, when trying to instrument a third-party class from an app running in Glassfish I get an error:

> Failed instrumenting
>   com.app.class
>
> agent.internal.javassist.CannotCompileException: cannot
>   find org.springframework.class

So it looks like the javaagent is able to fetch the bytecode of the class, but can't compile it, because some dependencies of the instrumented method (from `org.springframework`) can't be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unusual behaviour, as one would expect javassist to simply append bytecode to the instrumented method without having to refer to any classes referenced in that same method.

I could debug the problem through inspecting the ClassPool that the agent uses:

```
ClassPool pool = new ClassPool();
pool.appendSystemPath();
CustomLogger.logText("Class pool: " + pool.toString());
```

resulting in:

> Class pool: [class path:
>   my.java.agent.Transformer.class:java.lang.Object.class:]

We can then insert exact path (on the machine where agent will run!) to the missing library *.jar into the classPool:

```
pool.insertClassPath("/path/to/glassfish/modules/missing-module.jar");
```

Which results in:

> Class pool: [class path:
>   file:/path/to/glassfish/modules/missing-module.jar:my.java.agent.Transformer.class:java.lang.Object.class:]

javassist can now compile the class